# (newbie) strstr() returns null with unsigned param

Tags: c, string, parsing, pointers, unsigned

I have problem with this piece of code >

```
int parse_useragent (unsigned char* buf )
{
    int i;
    for (i=1; i < 200; i++)
    {
        printf("%c ", buf[i-1]); // this prints string with "User-Agent" inside
    }

    unsigned char * scanner = strstr(buf, "User-Agent:"); //returns NULL?

    if (scanner == NULL)
    {
        printf("NULL!!! /n");
        return DEFAULT_USERAGENT;
    }

    /* ... */
```

The `strstr` function returns NULL although that the substring is there...
I believe there is problem with **unsigned** char* buf, is there any way of quick conversion so I will be able to use `strstr` function?

Comment: You said, that buf contains "User-Agent" (without colon), but you are searching for "User-Agent:" (with colon)

Comment: I doubt the signedness would be the problem, since `buf` would be converted to a `char*` when you pass it as the argument.

Comment: First of all, is `buf` guaranteed to be null-terminated? Also, your `strstr()` would match an `User-Agent:` in the middle of a line.

Comment: CyberDem0n : Tried with "User" with same problem
Michal : not quaranteed to be null terminated...

Comment: I parse http packet data, so the buf does not contain something crazy...

Comment: Can you include the output of your run?

Comment: @TomášŠíma: if it's not null-terminated, then you simply can't use `strstr()` on it. And you really can't use it without passing the size of the data inside somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print your buffer correctly to know where null characters may appear:

```
printf("%s\n", buf);
```

You have several problems with your approach:

- <strike>`buf[0]` may already be a null character, arrays in C start at `0` and not at `1`</strike>
- `%c` might print nothing when it encounters a null character
- `strstr` stops at the first null character

Comment: This helped, it doesnt show anything what i saw when printing by characters, thanks...